# unusual extra space after semicolons in math mode using Springer Nature template

Tags: math-mode, templates, document-classes, springernature

For reasons I don't understand, the Springer Nature LaTeX authoring template (available via [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq) and on [Springer Nature's site](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support)) causes extra space to be inserted after semicolons in math mode.

For example, the following MWE yields:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,pdflatex]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    (x,y)\quad (x;y)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Springer Nature template semicolon spacing]

Whereas replacing the first line with `\documentclass{article}` yields the expected spacing:

[image: Normal spacing]

Is it possible to override this behavior in my document without altering the sn-jnl.cls file directly?  In particular, is it possible to do this in a more elegant way than e.g. replacing every instance of `;` in my document with `{;}` or `/!/!;` ?

**Edit:** As @egreg points out in his answer, the spacing after the semicolon can be avoided by disabling the loading of the `program` package.  However, this approach somehow causes errors (that are not present when the `program` package is allowed to load) when using the proof environment:
[image: Proof Errors]

**Second Edit:** From the comment of @egreg below, a satisfactory solution is given by placing the following before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{program}{} %prevent program package from loading
\makeatother

\documentclass[sn-mathphys,pdflatex]{sn-jnl} 

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\opensquare}}} %fix class bug with proof environment
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sn-jnl` class loads, for no apparent reason, the package `program` that does silly settings and is the cause of a lot of problems with the class.

In particular, the package defines the semicolon as math active to produce, in math mode, the standard semicolon as punctuation followed by a thick space.

You can disable loading the package `program`.

```
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{program}{}
\makeatother

\documentclass[sn-mathphys,pdflatex]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    (x,y)\quad (x;y)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Complain with Springer that they should, at least, provide an option for not loading `program`.

[image]

Comment: This approach nicely addresses the spacing issue for semicolons in math-mode.  Unfortunately, it also causes errors when using the `proof` environment (see the edit to my question)

Comment: @user143410 That's a bug in the class. Add to your preamble `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\opensquare}}}`