# The problem of using qcircuit package in Sringer Nature journal latex template

Tags: packages, springernature, qcircuit, program

I cannot use qcircuit package in Springer Nature journal template, the latex template for Springer journal papers. It makes an error when I use that package in that template. Could anybody please help me?

Comment: Please include a minimal working example (MWE) that demonstrates your issue. And please share the actual error message that you're getting.

Comment: if asking about an error show the full error message from the log

Comment: Use standalone and \includegraphics.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `sn-jnl` class loads the package `program`. From CTAN:

> its main offering is a program environment; a programbox environment
> is available for fragments that must not break with the pages.

Unfortunately, it defines a command `\push`  that conflicts with the `qcircuit` package. If you don't need such  "programbox environment", you can avoid loading the package `program`.

Using the solution from [disable loading the package program](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664189/161015)

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\makeatletter% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\disable@package@load{program}{}
\makeatother

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{qcircuit}

\begin{document}

\centerline{%
        \Qcircuit @C=1em @!R {
            \lstick{\ket{x}}   &   \qw   &   \ctrl{1}   &   \qw   &   \rstick{\ket{x}}   \qw                     \\
            \lstick{\ket{y}}   &   \qw   &   \ctrl{1}   &   \qw   &   \rstick{\ket{y}}   \qw                     \\
            \lstick{\ket{z}}   &   \qw   &   \targ      &   \qw   &   \rstick{\ket{x \oplus (y \wedge z})} \qw
        }
}

\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thank you very much. I worked for me and the problem solved!